# For /f loop in batch comprehension

Tags: batch-file

its so easy (or it should) but probably i have an comprehension problem.
However:
I have an simple File with two numbers in it 0 and 1

And this snippet:

```
set adp=
for /f %%i in (file.txt) do (
set adp=%%i
call :test
)
:test 
echo ADP %adp%
```

So I expect to get as result
ADP 0
ADP 1

but i get

ADP 0
ADP 1
ADP 1

Why do i get three results instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the batch file goes to `:test` after the loop, no matter what.

You should do something like this :

```
set adp=
for /f %%i in (file.txt) do (
  set adp=%%i
  call :test
)
goto :end

:test 
echo ADP %adp%

:end
```

Comment: Facepalm   
Thank you - i knew its easy - but i didn´t figured it out.